# Pipe cat/grep/arguments into variable in bash script

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, cat

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
HOUR=`date +%H`
ORDERS_THIS_HOUR=`cat cli.log | grep $DATE $HOUR | grep -o "generated for Production" | wc -l`
OUTPUT="$DATE $HOUR : $ORDERS_THIS_HOUR"

echo "$OUTPUT" >> flow_productivity.log
```

Issue is with the second line: `grep: 14: No such file or directory`.

Here is a sample command, the results of which I would like to store in `$ORDERS_THIS_HOUR`:

`cat cli.log | grep "2019-02-13 12" | grep -o "generated for Production" | wc -l`

Run from the command line, the above produces the expected output.

Comment: `grep "$DATE $HOUR"`. Quotes are important.

Comment: And btw, it'll be more efficient if you get rid of the `cat`, and make it `grep "$DATE $HOUR" <cli.log`

Comment: (Not an efficiency matter, but as an aside, it's better to avoid all-caps names for your own variables: All-caps is used for variables that impact system and shell behavior, so using that namespace opens you up to collisions; see the relevant POSIX standard document at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Comment: ...also, if the date always comes before the "generated for Production" string, you could make it something like `grep -Ec "$DATE $HOUR.*generated for Production" <cli.log`, collapsing the pipeline to just one command; no more FIFOs at all.

Comment: Got it everyone.  Thank you -bash is like stepping through a portal into another world for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First -- because you aren't putting quotes around your expansions, they're passed as separate arguments to `grep`. The first result of string-splitting and globbing `$DATE $HOUR` becomes the filename that `grep` searches through, and subsequent ones become filenames to search.

Beyond that, it's a bad idea to call `date` more than once in the same script anyhow. What if your script is run as the time passes midnight? You could have the first call to `date` be for the end of one day, and the second one return the very beginning of the next morning. To avoid this risk, call `date` only once, as in the following:

```
now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H')
msg="generated for Production"
orders_this_hour=$(grep -Ec "($now.*$msg|$msg.*$now)" <cli.log)
output="$now : $orders_this_hour"
echo "$output" >> flow_productivity.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It is taking `$HOUR` as filename. Make it `grep "$DATE $HOUR"`